# Keep a Service Alive in Android 7.1.1 with OxygenOS 4.1.6

Tags: android, android-service

Hi I want to  keep a service alive 
This is my service code

```
public class  Myservice1 extends Service{

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startdid){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"works",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

and this is my manifest file

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService1"
            android:enabled="true"

            />
```

This runs perfectly in android 7.0
But when I run it in android 7.1.1 with OxygenOS 4.1.6 in one plus 3T the service gets killed after app is closed from recent apps but the services from other apps like whatsapp and truecaller runs perfectly.

Comment: Make it a Foreground Service.

Comment: Use JobScheduler instead

Comment: On some devices you need to manually add apps to a list of "protected apps" or "apps that are allowed to run in the background". If your app is not in this list, Android will not restart it after BOOT or restart it after it is killed. This may be what you are seeing (WhatsApp and Truecaller are probably in that list of apps).